# Removing a 240v hard wired doorbell chime on a ring

Tags: electrical

My house had an old hardwired door bell that wasn't working properly when I purchased the house, so I removed the push button, put the cables on a terminal block and pushed them in to the wall, covered it over.

Now I want to remove the big yellowing plastic chime case thats on the wall. I've taken the cover off and inspected it - there are 2 240V red and black wires going in, so from this I can assume its on the ring for the plug sockets?

My first thought is a maintenance free junction box. Turn the power off to that ring, disconnect the 2 red and 2 black, connect in to the junction box and embed this in the wall, then patch over it.

Is this a reasonable solution?

Comment: You're in the UK or some other place that uses UK wiring standards, right?

Comment: If the doorbell was at 240 V I assume it had a fuse where it connected to the ring circuit. What was the limit on the fuse? The most we use in the US for a doorbell is 24 V AFIK. Mine is 20.0 V ac and not fused.

Comment: You can't cover up splices and bury them in walls.  99% of all wiring problems happen at splices, and if the splice gave any trouble, you'd never find it to fix it.

Comment: We're not familiar with rings in the US so I'm not sure what you are proposing. Is there a box where the doorbell spur is attached to the ring? You want to disconnect the spur at the ring and then cover this box up? This would be answerable only by someone familiar with UK systems. When the ring is tapped is there a splice in the ring or is the spur clipped onto the ring which is unbroken conductor?